# Adding secondary graphics card for third monitor

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have a Dell OptiPlex 960 with a dual-head ATI Radeon HD 4670 card (powering two monitors) installed in the PCIe x16 slot. I'm wanting to add a third monitor to my setup, and I'm aware that using the on-board graphics card is not an option. I have three slots that aren't being used: PCIe x1 and two PCI slots. With that being said, what are some options that will allow a third monitor? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

FYI: I am running Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: This has been asked a few times. Here is a link containing superuser [search options](http://superuser.com/search).

Comment: Why do you think using the on-board graphics is not an option? Windows 7 officially supports multiple monitors on different graphics cards with different drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get another radeon gfx card. If you want to do crossfire, you want a similarly specced card, but if they're separate you may or may not run into problems. Never tried the latter before.

EDIT:
You probably want a PCIe x16, but if you don't have an extra sitting in there, you should go with USB video like the other guy said.

Answer (score 1):

USB Video is the way to go. There are [dozens of USB video card solutions](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=usb+video+card&pbx=1&oq=usb+video+card&aq=f&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1716l3588l0l3807l14l9l0l2l2l1l281l1700l0.1.6l7l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=339f89ea28169800&biw=1920&bih=1041&safe=active), most support HD, etc.